# 'FB' is not defined in HounCI Test

Tags: javascript, facebook, testing, facebook-javascript-sdk, pull-request

I am using the following code to share an article via facebook.

```
$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '{app-id}',
            version: 'v2.5'
        });
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            display: 'popup',
            href: audio,
            caption: name,
            description: desc,
            picture: img
        });
    });
```

I am however encountering an issue that that `FB Object is not defined` when I make a pull request which is inspected by a js inspector.

Can someone explain how and at what point the FB Object is declared?

Thanks,.

Comment: Is that jQuery? According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/v2.5 that should work. Although they explicitly set `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });` before fetching the script there – but I doubt that should make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Load the SDK in following manner:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '{app-id}',
        version: 'v2.5'
    });
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'popup',
        href: audio,
        caption: name,
        description: desc,
        picture: img
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```